# Open automatically python file as Administrator

Tags: python

I want to use the third party module called "ping", [found here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ping/2011.10.17.376a019)

But it requires to open the file as "Administrator" in Windows.

I want it so every time the computer is started, to open this file as Administrator.
To open it, I just need to put the file in `shell:startup`

But the issue is that I need to do it as Administrator.
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

So there's this program called

> Task Scheduler you can find it just by pressing start and searching
>   "Task Scheduler"

[image: Looks like this.]

> So first you want to go to action then click create action.

[image: Should open a window that looks like this.]

> Go to triggers then select create new trigger configure it so it looks
>   like this.

[image: Trigger]

Then Create a batch script for launching your python file.
Somthing like this.

```
@echo off
python c:\somescript.py %*
pause
```

> then go to action on the window and create a new action.
>   [image: action page]
>
> last go to the main page configure it like this and click ok and done.
>   [image]

Comment: Thats requires me to do it by hand. I need to do this with code

Comment: You never said in your question that you wanted to write a script to do this kinda stuff so I'm flagging this  question.